# Elasticsearch query no working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the following Mysql SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `best_fares_GB` a 
WHERE is_dp=0 AND (origin_region = destination_region) AND
      (origin_country ='GB') AND (destination_city='MIL') AND 
      date_back IS NOT NULL, AND DATEDIFF(date_back,date_out)>=1 AND   
      DATEDIFF(date_back,date_out)<=7 AND DATEDIFF(date_out,CURDATE)<=90
```

Current mappings in Index as follows:

```
{
    "bestfares_data": {
        "properties": {
            "dateBack": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "basic_date",
              },
            "dateOut": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "basic_date",
              },
            "destinationAirport": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
            "destinationCity": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
            "destinationCountry": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
            "destinationRegion": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
            "isDpSubagent": {
                "type": "boolean",
              },
            "originAirport": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
            "originCity": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              },
            "originCountry": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
             },
            "originRegion": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
              }
        }
    }
}
```

My initial elasticsearch query is looking like:

```
{
     "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [ 
                { "match": { "originCountry" : "GB" }},
                { "match": { "destinationCity" : "MIL" }}
            ]
         }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "and": {
           "filters": [
              {
                  "exists":  {"field": "dateBack"}
              } ,
              {
                  "script" : {"script" : "doc[\"originRegion\"].value == doc[\"destinationRegion\"].value"}
              },
              {
                  "script" : {"script" : "doc[\"dateBack\"].value - doc[\"dateOut\"].value >= 1"}
              },
              {
                  "script" : {"script" : "doc[\"dateBack\"].value - doc[\"dateOut\"].value <= 7"}
              },
              {
                 "range": {
                    "dateOut": {
                       "gte": "now+1d",
                       "lte": "now+3M"
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        } 
    }
}
```

This is not working as expected.

If I removed the section:

```
{
    "script" : {
         "script" : "doc[\"dateBack\"].value - doc[\"dateOut\"].value <= 7"
    }
}
```

I can get valid results back, but as soon as I add this condition, I got zero hits, even when I know there are plenty of records satisfying this condition. Could someone point out what is wrong the previous query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a long shot, but what do you expect to be returned by subtracting to dates. You check smaller than 7. But what is 7 in your case? Do you mean days? Because I do not think this is happening. I am afraid you get back milliseconds. So what you are trying is to get back documents where the difference is between 1 and 7 milliseconds. Since you are only indexing dates the time for all the documents is 0:00:00.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Jettro, thanks a lot taking time to look at this. Is there any way to use date math in scripting as mentioned in (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) I've done some tests but always got errors.
Also is there any way to visualize the results of any calculations you do? For example if I want to show in the response of a query the results of: 
"doc[\"dateBack\"].value - doc[\"dateOut\"].value
is there any way to do that?